# Unexpected JAXB error

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

From the documentation it's clear I need to use the following to get a simple unmarshalling to occur from my XML file/schema:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("PackageName");
```

where PackageName is my package name.  I've looked on google for a bit to no avail, to find out why I'm then getting this runtime error:

```
Line:Col[2:142]:cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'myconfig'.
Line:Col[2:142]:unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org", local:"myconfig"). Expected elements are <{}myconfig>
Caught UnmarshalException
```

**EDIT**: 
Note: the plugin forced me to specify a package name.  I gave it the same package as all my application class files are in as I wanted all the JAXB classes and my app together.  If my package is `PackageName`, it then created all the JAXB class files in `PackageName.PackageName`.  I then had to move them out of `PackageName.PackageName` (which it automatically created) back into the tree where my app is (`PackageName`).  This doesn't feel right to me.
**EDIT END**

The following occurs at the top of all my class files, including the ones the XJC JAXB plugin for eclipse created for me:

```
package PackageName;
```

so why is this error occurring?

**EDIT**:
The schema is quite big so I don't want to paste it all in here, and the `ObjectFactory.java` file is consequently quite large.  It begins

```
package PackageName;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
```

and ends

```
/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link MyConfigType }{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "myconfig")
public JAXBElement<MyConfigType> createMyconfig(MyConfigType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<MyConfigType>(_Myconfig_QNAME, MyConfigType.class, null, value);
}
```

So all quite standard.  The top of the schema (I'm an XML schema newb and this was supplied to me), is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

which also looks straight forward.  The schema for the root element is this:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyConfigType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="tips" type="TipType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:key name="unique_abc_id">
                <xs:selector xpath="./abc" />
                <xs:field xpath="@id" />
            </xs:key>
            <xs:key name="unique_def_id">
                <xs:selector xpath="./def" />
                <xs:field xpath="@id" />
            </xs:key>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="noNamespaceschemaLocation" />
</xs:complexType>
```

The supplied config which I'm asking it to validate at the same time as unmarshal starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<myconfig xmlns="http://www.w3.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceschemaLocation="myconfig.xsd">
    <firsttag...>
```

I'm stumped.

**EDIT END**

Answer (score 1):

For this to work:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("PackageName");
```

You need to have one or both of these:

- an ObjectFactory.class in that directory
- a jaxb.index file. This file should contain a list of class names in that package.

Either of those would describe the classes that should be available to JAXB.

Comment: Ah. Sorry forgot to mention, I already had xjc create the objectfactory.java file -it's in with the schema reference files. Where do I go next?

Comment: @Mark Lewis I would need some more information about the classes itself. It looks a schema validation issue but without seeing the Class I don't know if I can tell you much.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've edited some problem code into my question to flesh it out a bit.  Maybe that will illustrate my issue in more depth. Thanks IA